# Django advanced model operation

Tags: sql, django, django-models, model

I do have such operation:
Contact.objects.filter(contact_code__icontains=my_string[-8:]).exists()

I want to find my_string[-8:] not in the beggining, not at the end but strictly on x position in contact_code. Or I want to splite contact_code field, them do MD5 on it and only then look on it?
How can I manipulate model query here? I can do it in raw sql and want to do it in model filter - not in code.

Answer (score 1):

I think u should use [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#iregex)

or
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#iregex
depending on whether the letters are case-sensitive

Comment: Entry.objects.get(title__iregex=r'^(an?|the) +')  THANKS!!!!